# How to filter many conditions in months of the same year?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I want to filter my database in transaction in May and June 2017. Here's my syntax but it was false:

```
SELECT
    order_buyer.buyer_id 
FROM order_buyer 
WHERE month(createdAt)=5 
AND month(createdAt)=6 
AND year(createdAt)=2017 
GROUP BY order_buyer.buyer_id;
```

Comment: As I understand from your description, you want all records of the month May and June. So in your query your where clause should look like this 

where (month(createdAt)=5 OR month(createdAt)=6) and year(createdAt)=2017 group by order_buyer.buyer_id;

and operator is like logically AND i.e. both conditions should be true which is never possible a date can have single month only. hope I could clarified this. You may refer this linkhttps://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php

Comment: thankyou for your advice, but when i try it, it became the random data who appear in may and june or may/june only

Comment: can you show some sample data, and what is expected output

Answer (score 1):

This is because your query is invalid, remember SQL is based on asking logical questions and you are asking the below question:

"Please give me the the buyer ID from Order_buyer where the month is 5 & 6?"

That is not possible as no record can be "MayJune" and dependent on your platform it will either error or ignore the where clause.

You will need to use an OR statement for this query:

```
SELECT 
  order_buyer.buyer_id 
FROM 
  order_buyer 
WHERE 
  (
    month(createdAt)= 5 
    OR month(createdAt)= 6
  ) 
  and year(createdAt)= 2017 
GROUP BY 
  order_buyer.buyer_id;
```

I believe this should work, let me know how you get on! :D